# shortcode to find and replace the url and image src

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, shortcode

i have to get the content and find the url from the content and replace it with the another default url.whatever content is there i have to find the href and replace it with the default url.

The shortcode changes every url to a new random cat using this simple API: http://random.cat/meow

Example:

```
[demo_shortcode]<a href="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"><img alt="A boring image of something other than a cat." src="http://i.imgur.com/BTNIDBR.gif"></a>[/demo_shortcode]
```

Outputs:

```
<a href="http://random.cat/i/eMMDP.jpg"><img alt="A boring image of something other than a cat." src="http://random.cat/i/zUhVw.jpg"></a>
```

for try i am trying this to get

```
function demo_function( $atts, $content = ""){
    $pattern = '(<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>)';
  $varr=file_get_contents('http://random.cat/meow');
 $content = preg_replace($pattern,$varr,$content);
return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'demo_shortcode', 'demo_function' );
```

[demo_shortcode][/demo_shortcode]

Output : `<a href=”http://random.cat/i/QRp74.jpg“></a>`

this replaces the href to the required url but also replaces the image.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Hope it might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205667/regular-expression-to-searchreplace-href-url

Comment: i want to replace both href and image src with one shortcode..this only add the url to the href

Comment: You could break up your content string, use explode on the < for example - then run your preg_replace on just the part you need - then put it all back together.

Comment: i have tried it but for explode we have to put a special character which is not correct solution                                                                                                    [demo_shortcode]<a href="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">@<img alt="A boring image of something other than a cat." src="http://i.imgur.com/BTNIDBR.gif"></a>[/demo_shortcode]